# Why Yii2 captcha can't through the verification On the client side?

Tags: ajax, yii2, captcha

I am using Yii2 *admin* Module, the captcha image is shown on the form. After I input the verifycode, tips always shown the error message on the client side, but I'm sure it was entered correctly. Then I view the source code, I found I didn't set the attribute `captchaAction` (`\yii\captcha\CaptchaValidator`) correctly, the default value of **`captchaAction`** is `site/captcha`, but my controller is `app\modules\admin\controllers\PublicController`, I think that the value of captchaAction should be `admin/public/captcha`, but how to set it ?

The following is my view page code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className(), [
    'template' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-lg-4">{image}</div> &nbsp;<div class="col-lg-7">{input}</div></div>',
    'captchaAction' => 'public/captcha',
 ]); ?>
```

Here is my controller：

```
public function actions()
{
    return [
        'error' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
        ],
        'captcha' => [
            'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
            'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            'minLength' => 3,
            'maxLength' => 5,
        ],
    ];
}
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ( Yii::$app->request->isPost ) {
        # code ...
    } else {
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
            'title' => Yii::$app->params['adminLogin'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful with form which is validated by AJAX. Captcha of Yii will be reload if you validate by Ajax. So with this case, we can solve with two option:

1. Disable `ajaxValidation`, enable `clientValidation`. Such as: signup form

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id'                     => 'registration-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'   => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => false
]);
```

2. Override function validate of `CaptchaAction`, don't `getVerifyCode` through AJAX.

```
if(\Yii::$app->request->isAjax == false) {
    $this->getVerifyCode(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When using captcha outside the SiteController, you should make changes in 3 files:

1. Define captchaAction in your Model route method where you have defined captcha validation itself:

   ```
   function rules()
   {
       return [
           ...
           ["verificationCode", "captcha", 'captchaAction' => 'your-controller/captcha']
       ];
   }
   ```
2. Define captcha action in your controller:

   ```
   public function actions()
   {
       return [
           'error' => [
               'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
           ],
           'captcha' => [
               'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
               'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
           ],
       ];
   }
   ```
3. Change image rendering action in the view file:

   ```
   <?= $form->field($model,
       "verificationCode")->widget( Captcha::className(), [
           'captchaAction' => 'your-controller/captcha'
       ]); ?>
   ```

Comment: Indeed! 'captchaAction' in the rules has helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### The problem and a better solution.

Basically the problem is usually caused when setting `enableAjaxValidation` for the entire active form, with code like the following.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'some-id',
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
]); ?>
```

The default is to use client slide validation, however sometimes things can only be validated server-side, so this feature can be nice. In addition to the global option, each individual input can specify the use of `enableAjaxValidation` or not. For some reason however, the Captcha widget does not explicitly set it to `false`.

In most cases where AJAX validation is required for some inputs, it's probably best to leave it off be default, and enable it for the controls you want. For example, if we had a user registration form, where we have a AJAX validator to check for duplicate usernames, we can enable it for just that one input.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'username', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'verifyCode')->widget(Captcha::className()) ?>
```

Doing it this way also gives us some other benefits, such as reducing AJAX requests by validating that which you can client-side, and giving faster response time where possible.

---

### Not-So-Great Alternative to the Above:

Here's an older, alternate solution based on [@AnHuy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29118007/3155639).

In the controller with the `captcha` action (`SiteController` if using the Yii2 starter projects), find the `actions` section .

```
    public function actions() {
        return [
            // ...
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
            // ...
        ];
    }
```

Replace `yii\captcha\CaptchaAction` with your own class path which will subclass the Yii action, in this case I will use `app\models\captcha\CaptchaAction`.

```
    public function actions() {
        return [
            // ...
            'captcha' => [
                'class' => 'app\models\captcha\CaptchaAction',
                'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
            ],
            // ...
        ];
    }
```

Now create the action subclass, in this case `models/captcha/CaptchaAction.php`.

```
<?php

namespace app\models\captcha;

use Yii;
use yii\captcha\CaptchaAction as CaptchaActionBase;

class CaptchaAction extends CaptchaActionBase {
    public function validate($input, $caseSensitive) {
        // Skip validation on AJAX requests, as it expires the captcha.
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            return true;
        }
        return parent::validate($input, $caseSensitive);
    }
}
```

Basically it checks if it's the AJAX validation check, and returns true in this case, skipping the expiring validation check. If not, it runs the validation as normal.

Comment: I am using Ajax Form Submit, I have tried your first suggestion, but the form gets submitted without validating captcha.

Answer (score 0):

change model form  rules

```
   ['verifyCode', 'captcha','captchaAction'=>'public/captcha' ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have 'captcha' in access rules for your role

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['captcha', (whatever ...)],
                    'allow' => true,
                ],
```

....